# How do I change text in a cell based on another cell?

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I have a cell in Excel (lets say A1) that containes the text "+ 0.2% of foo"... I'd like to be able to change the percentage value in that cell based on text in another cell (for example, C1).  Like, if i change C1 to 0.6%, then A1 would change to "+ 0.6% of foo".

I've found bunches of stuff on changing colors based on cells and things, but changing text blocks inside cells seems to be harder to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate using `&`

```
="+ " & TEXT(C1,"0.0%") & " of foo"
```